# Docker MySQL - can't connect from Spring Boot app to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

What I'm trying to do is, connect from my spring-boot app to mysql database in Docker. Each in their own container.

But I must be having something wrong because I can't do it.

**To keep it simple :**

application-properties :

```
# URL for the mysql db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://workaround-mysql:3308/workaround?serverTimezone=UTC&max_allowed_packet=15728640
# User name in mysql
spring.datasource.username=springuser
# Password for mysql
spring.datasource.password=admin
#Port at which application runs
server.port=8080
```

docker-compose for MySQL:

```
version: '3'
services:
  workaround-mysql:
    container_name: workaround-mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: workaround
      MYSQL_USER: springuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    restart: always
```

So pretty simple right ? Database I start with `docker-compose up`:

[image]

All seems to be working fine so far.

Now that I have db started, to the application, this is its `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

  workaround:
    restart: always
    # will build ./docker/workaround/Dockerfile
    build: ./docker/workaround
    working_dir: /workaround
    volumes:
      - ./:/workaround
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: "mvn clean spring-boot:run"
```

For its `Dockerfile` I use Linux Alpine and Java.

```
FROM alpine:3.9
....add java...
RUN apk update
RUN apk add dos2unix --update-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add maven
```

Super simple. Now let's start the application :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unknown host, so let's try the IP then :

```
    docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' workaround-mysql

# URL for the mysql db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.20.0.2:3308/workaround?serverTimezone=UTC&max_allowed_packet=15728640
```

Now I get timeout:

[image]

As you can see I get error. What is wrong with my setup and how to fix
this? Either I have unknown host exception or Refused to connect or connection timeout.

I have tried:

- Using ip of a container in my application.properties, didn't work
- Different ports for MySQL and application
- Different images and versions of MySQL
- Having everything in one docker compose with wait
- timer for database.
- Minimal setup with
  https://github.com/hellokoding/hellokoding-courses/tree/master/docker-examples/dockercompose-springboot-mysql-nginx
  Also resulted in communication link failure, Site was accessible but I
  doubt that db was connected properly.

**Notes**:

- I run this all on one computer I use port 3308 because I have local
  MySQL db at 3306.
- Here is `docker ps -a`

[image]

@Vusal ANSWER output :

[image]

Only thing different from code in answer I did wait for database to be ready 30 seconds

```
command: /bin/bash -c "sleep 30;mvn clean spring-boot:run;"
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using docker network between the containers?

Comment: @ChristianW. I dont know much about them, I have tried to put things into same network. Bud I still didnt had any success.  With NETWORK : WORKAROUND on both defined. (bud maybe i didnt do something there correctly)

Comment: Those things should be in a single docker compose, else it won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum During one of my tries i have done that , im currently doing it again to make sure i didnt messed up, from answers down bellow :)

Comment: @M.Deinum Still getting error Connection refused  even when they are on same network

Comment: Any updates regarding this issue ? I have the same thing

Comment: @Aguid yes, it was configuration issue, i think ports if i remember correctly, check accepted answer, make sure your ports are setup properly. See comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  workaround-mysql:
    container_name: workaround-mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: workaround
      MYSQL_USER: springuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    restart: always
  workaround:
    depends_on: 
      - workaround-mysql
    restart: always
    # will build ./docker/workaround/Dockerfile
    build: ./docker/workaround
    working_dir: /workaround
    volumes:
      - ./:/workaround
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8080"
    command: "mvn clean spring-boot:run"
```

And update your `application.properties` to use the next JDBC connection url:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://workaround-mysql:3306/workaround?serverTimezone=UTC&max_allowed_packet=15728640
```

It should work when both containers in the same docker-compose file, because docker-compose creates default network for containers, so they can resolve each other by name.

Comment: I will try it out

Comment: Ok so after  I have used code you send me , I have Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) I already had that before when i tried this approach. No success, Will update question with full output

Comment: Updated question with output to your answer.

Comment: I will test since i still used that 3308 , I will change it to 3306 and see if it changes from connection refused

Answer (score 3):

What you haven't tried so far is running both containers on the same Docker network.

First, forget about IP addressing - using it should be avoided by all means.

Second, launch both compose instances with the same Docker network.

Third, **do not** expose ports - inside bridge network all ports are accessible to running containers.

1. Create global network

   ```
    docker network create foo
   ```
2. Modify both compose files so that they use this network instead of creating each one its own:

   ```
    version: '3.5'
    services:

    ....

    networks:
      default:
        external: true
        name: foo
   ```
3. Remove `expose` directives from compose files - inside one network all ports are exposed by default
4. Modify connection strings to use default `3306` port instead of `3308`
5. Enjoy

Comment: Will try it out

Comment: Bud if i remove use of 3308 I will clash with 3306 that i have running locally already (mysql database)  that i test with from intellij ? Right?

Comment: services.workaround-mysql.networks.default contains unsupported option: 'external' and  services.workaround-mysql.networks.default contains unsupported option: 'name'

Comment: Put `version: '3.5'` or later at the top of yaml files

Comment: "Bud if i remove use of 3308 I will clash with 3306 that i have running locally already (mysql database) that i test with from intellij ? Right?" No, you wont. `3306` will exist only inside network `foo` and will NOT be available outside. As far as I understood, you connect to db from another container, not from host. If I am wrong and you also need to connect from host, you will need to expose ports

Comment: Tried version 3.5 and 3.7 still getting unsupported option on external keyword (when i do docker-compose build)

Comment: `docker-compose --version`?

Comment: docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: I've double checked this syntax, can you verify you have no misspellings and correct tabulation? Note - `networks` directive is **GLOBAL**, not related to any particular service

Comment: My fault didnt have it global ;) I have put it under service so that might be the case .Either way problem is solved by info in your answer will probably be used to further refine what i have now :D awesome

Answer (score 2):

In order for the service to connect with MySql through docker it has to be in same network, look into Docker network

But for better solution I would suggest you to write a single docker compose file for MySql and Spring boot.The reason is it will easily be linked when you do that.No need any other configuration.

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
  spring-service:
    image: springservce:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service
```

Comment: Getting connection refused with this style of compose file.

Comment: The jdbc url in application.properties should be something like this "url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306/db" (In docke-compse.yml, I have mentioned my service name as 'mysql-service' and DB name as 'db' that's why have used the same value in the  URL ).Same goes for username and password

Comment: @TomasBisciak, for you reference https://github.com/aviu95/user_mgt look into the code

Comment: Yes i made it work! Your answer was pretty close to what accepted answer is . Pretty much same, so thank you so much also!!

Answer (score -1):

Before you try to connect to the Docker container you should stop mysql in your computer then go to the application.properties and type:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/NAME_OF_YOUR_DB_HERE?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Regarding localhost, you should inspect the mysql container and pick the IP address and use it instead. most likely is 172.17.0.2. If it did not work then use localhost.

Comment: `localhost` will _not_ work in Docker; from the Spring application's point of view, it will refer to the Spring application container and not the database container.  The other answers to this question have better Docker-specific setups.